# Simple slider rating system from 1-5

Tags: rating

I was thinking about adding a rating system to my website, like a 5 star rating system but with a slider instead. (A simple slider with steps from 1-5). What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a normal range type input, set the range from 1 to 5.

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="5" step="1">
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the value to be the average rating, and that should be updated every time a visitor ranks my work.(By dragging the same slider..)

Comment: Well thats the html element you would need. You would need to write a bit of javascript to get it to function the way you want. First you'd have to write a function to set it on page load to your average rating, and a change function that runs when it is moved to store the new rating.

Comment: What are you using to store your data?

Comment: At the moment nothing.. But I've got A wordpress site running on Php My SQL.

Comment: You need to break your problem up in to smaller, more easily managed problems. Figure out how to store a value in a field in the database. Get that value to appear within an html element on your webpage. Store multiple values, get multiple values to print to your page in a similar manner. Toy around with javascript and get the average of these values. When you calculate the average correctly, set the initial position of your slider to the average. Then mess around with javascript some more until you can grab data from the slider after a change (user moved it). Be resourceful.